# JScrollBar: Stop knob moving further upon hit certain value

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I'd like to ask is it possible to stop knob moving further upon hit certain value in JScrollBar ?

For example, set the minimum and maximum value of a vertical scroll bar to 0 and 100. If the user scroll the knob till 60, he or she should not be able to move knob up further but able to move knob down.

Hence, I have simply wrote following adjust listener:

```
class MyAdjustmentListener2 implements AdjustmentListener 
{
  public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) 
  {
     label.setText("New Value is " + e.getValue() + " ");
     if (e.getValue() < 60 ) 
     {
        vbar.setValue(60);
     }
  }
}
```

The label is a JLabel I used to monitor the adjusted value, the vbar is a vertical JScrollBar instance. Above code will force the knob jump back to value 60 if user try to move it above the value 60. This slightly different from what I want to achieve.

I have looked into the API of JScrollBar, I didn't found any straight method provided to use. Please share some hints to me here. Thank you for your time and suggestion.

Comment: Why?  The concept seems counterintuitive to me. Sorry to be pain, but having some idea of what you are hoping to achieve might give us some more idea of how to help...

Comment: I'd like to explain. Cause the entire image(size very big) is reuse in different panels. In different panel, the users only can view different portions of image. However, within the given portion, the user is free to scroll. In order to achieve that, first, I set the view position of viewport differently. Second, I need to limit the user's scrolling area to certain percentage. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: *"I hope it's more clear now."*  It's pretty clear that each view should contain a sub image (as opposed to stuffing with the user's ability to scroll).

Comment: Andrew Thompson, Thanks for the reply. But the challenging part is the entire image should be load in the different panels. Not the sub image of it. Stupid, right ?

Comment: *"Stupid, right ?"*  So much so that I will give no more attention to this nonsense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. But that's the real life situation.